# Oil level indicator on my 2005 Caddy CTS message center does not indicate problem, even though oil level is dangerously low.

Tags: oil, cadillac, cts

Is this indicator controlled by a fuse?

Comment: How low is "dangerously low" in your case?

Comment: I had to add three quarts of oil to get oil level to bottom of dipstick.  I was lucky I had stopped for gas on long trip.

Comment: The oil level indicator on the CTS should be triggered by an oil level switch that screws into the sump. You should check that. I doubt it has a dedicated fuse.